# asctime time output error

Tags: c, time

```
#include<time.h>
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void)
 {
 time_t timer;
 int i;
 char mon[4];
 char *ti=0;
 ti=asctime(localtime(&timer));
 ti=ti+4;
 for(i=0;i<3;i++)
 {
  mon[i]=*ti++;

 }
  mon[3]='\0';

 timer=time(NULL);
  printf("The current time is %s\n",mon);
  return 0;
 }
```

Hi, Can anyone expalin why asctime returns wrong time-pointer sometimes.Iam using 'mon' to store the month from asctime string and when printing it on the console,it displays sometimes 'Mar' and sometimes some other month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `timer` without initializing it. Before calling `localtime`, try:

```
time(&timer);
```

Also, a simpler way to do it would be:

```
ctime(&timer);
```